# Following Para installation steps and getting "Connection failed. Run "para-cli setup" or check the configuration file"

Tags: para

I am on Ubuntu 20.04

The `para` jar is running.

I have followed the "Quick Start" steps in [Erudika Para Github repo](https://github.com/Erudika/para)

At the step to run `para-cli setup`.

I am prompted for `Para Access Key`.

I am prompted for `Para Secret Key`.

I am prompted for `Para Endpoint` to which `http://localhost:8080` is answered.

The file `/home/ace/.config/para-cli-nodejs/config.json` is generated and looks fine.

It matches the `accessKey` and `secretKey` from the previously executed `curl` command to `http://localhost:8080/v1/_setup`

The problem is `para-cli setup` ends with:

> ✔ New JWT generated and saved in
> /home/ace/.config/para-cli-nodejs/config.json

> ✖ Connection failed. Run
> "para-cli setup" or check the configuration file
> /home/ace/.config/para-cli-nodejs/config.json

I am now stuck.  Why is the connection failing?

This is the content of the `config.json` (this is a test app so secret key is not really secret)

```
{
        "accessKey": "app:para",
        "secretKey": "mMEzD6pTGhqbt8n4n3UMTBl1dH9dWTsK6KDThiDFyeLJLzrnRKXCug==",
        "endpoint": "http://localhost:8080",
        "jwt": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1OTUwNDk0MDksImlhdCI6MTU5NDQ0NDYwOSwibmJmIjox>
}
```

This is the output of the initially run `curl http://localhost:8080/v1/_setup`

```
{
  "accessKey" : "app:para",
  "message" : "Save these keys - they are shown only once!",
  "secretKey" : "mMEzD6pTGhqbt8n4n3UMTBl1dH9dWTsK6KDThiDFyeLJLzrnRKXCug=="
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your Para server is running and accessible from the machine you run `para-cli` on. Sometimes when your database is not configured properly the initialization of the root app is not persisted and the secret key you get changes each time you call `curl http://localhost:8080/v1/_setup`. Open `http://localhost:8080/v1/_setup` and make sure you see "All set!".

Use `para-cli ping` to test the connection to your Para server before creating a new app.

Comment: Thanks albogdano.  The issue was `para.security.api_security` should be set to `true`.  This is in the `application.conf` file.